# behavior of divs with float=left, need to receive the same behavior when thay are at the div-container

Tags: html, css, css-float

**Remember:**
Imagine the behavior on the screen of those elements: `<div>` with style `float: left; height: 100px; width: 100px` when there is more then 100 on the screen. When you resize your window to the low width: **divs will being pushed down**

**Example**
http://1lj.net/ex2.html

**What I need:** 
I need the child divs to act like the linked example, the problem is that they are in a fixed width container. eg. `<div class=container style="width:800px">`

**How to get this behaviour?**

sorry for my english, its really hard to write on not native language.

Comment: What ? Can you add a picture ? I read this 3 times and still dont know what you mean

Comment: I'm sorry, but this doesn't make any sense. `wight` is not a real word. I assume `weight` and `wight` are supposed to be 'width', but it still doesn't make any sense.

Comment: sorry, its my english :( I add the example of behavior without parent div with fixed width. !!! width !! ohhh

Comment: I updated the question for you, as far as I know you can't do this unless you  have a wrapper div that is 100%

Comment: question rewrited. seems now its easy to understand. thanks for somebody (does not remember the name) that give me the right phrase to describe behavior: `being pushed down`

Comment: @DavidNguyen thanks for update. yes, I am also does not know other ways right now... but design with fixed width :( Maybe need to put design at the bottom layout or something like this and its will be the way... searching the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two containers. One container is for the max width, the other is to hold the boxes.

CSS:

```
.container
{
    height:auto;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #666666;
}

.containercontent {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container"> <!-- Add this container -->
<div class="containercontent">

<h2>Lalalalal.</h2>

<div class="box" id=box1></div>
<div class="box" id=box2></div>
<div class="box" id=box3></div>
<div class=box id=box4></div>
<div class=box id=box5></div>
<div class=box id=box6></div>
<div class=box id=box7></div>
<div class=box id=box8></div>
<div class=box id=box9></div>
<div class=box id=box10></div>
<div class=box id=box11></div>
<div class=box id=box12></div>
<div class=box id=box13></div>
<div class=box id=box14></div>
<div class=box id=box15></div>
<div class=box id=box16></div>
<div class=box id=box17></div>
<div class=box id=box18></div>
<div class=box id=box19></div>
<div class=box id=box20></div>

</div>
<div class="clean"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice, somebody wrote that its impossible, but that seems exactly what i want.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div style="float:left;width:500px"></div><div style="float:left;width:500px"></div>
```

will become ...

```
 <div style="float:left;width:500px"></div>
 <div style="float:left;width:500px"></div>  ( like text wraps)
```

... when the window size is not wide enough to hold them

to prevent this, add a container with a width...

```
 <div style="width:1000px">
  <div style="float:left;width:500px"></div><div style="float:left;width:500px"></div>
 </div>
```

- only using inline style for ease of demonstration

Update as comments: for none fixed widths, same , but use percentages

```
  <div style="width:100%">
  <div style="float:left;width:50%"></div><div style="float:left;width:50%"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: +1; I believe fixed width container is what the OP is after. But *please* use classes or other semantic ways of applying styling! Also: clearfix is important for the parent container!

Comment: Hi Ov, my comment explains I am only using inline styling for demonstration purposes. I felt, clearfix would have just confused the answer.
fwiw - I prefer to not use the clearfix class and add a div with clear:both after any floats. what ever puts the nail in hey,  cheers, rob